# dockerized jenkins crashes since a Java allocation memory

Tags: java, jenkins, docker

I'm running `jenkins` image using docker:

```
docker run -d --name jenkins -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 -u root
  -v /root/jenkins/data/:/var/jenkins_home -e JAVA_OPTS="-Xmx2g"
  --add-host=docker:10.129.2.232
  jenkins
```

It crashes with a `native allocation memory` problem:

> OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO:
>   os::commit_memory(0x0000000083e80000, 1366294528, 0) failed;
>   error='Cannot allocate memory' (errno=12)
>
> There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
>
> Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 1366294528 bytes for committing reserved memory.
>   An error report file with more information is saved as:
>   //hs_err_pid5.log

Comment: Have you tried without `-e JAVA_OPTS = "-Xmx2g"` ? Does the container have >2GB of memory available in the first place?

Comment: Yes've already tried without any `JAVA_OPTS` specification and the problem remains. My server has 2Gb.

Answer (score 0):

If i correctly understood, your server has 2 Gb. and you cannot allocate 2 Gb. to Java as it is also used by the system.

Can you try with the parameter:

"-e JAVA_OPTS="-Xmx1536m""

?